# If Juggernaut Charged the Blob

Tags: marvel, x-men

If the Unstoppable Juggernaut ran head first into the Immovable Blob, what would happen? I have checked several sources, but have had no luck so far.

Comment: isn't this just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irresistible_force_paradox

Comment: I'm sure it's happened at least once in the Marvel universe...

Comment: Looking over Ryan Otterman's question history, I'm thinking someone just needs to buy him a copy of [X-Men: Next Dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Next_Dimension).

Comment: There is some hyperbole in both characters descriptions. But the way I remember it Juggernaut is more unstoppable than Blob is immovable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Juggernaut would move the Blob and a large chunk of the ground that the Blob was standing on.

Comment: It's important to remember that the Immovable Blob gets moved quite a bit pretty often. Even in his first appearance, Cyclops knocks him around with just his eye blasts.

Comment: Blob was never immovable, he merely generated a strong gravitational force beneath himself. Anyone capable of arbitrarily-large strength could move him.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer, the Blob would be budged.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities):

> The only beings on record to have been able to move the Blob against his wishes are the Hulk, **Juggernaut**, and Strong Guy (powered-up near his limit by absorbing kinetic energy) ...

Comment: _Strong Guy_. He must of been last in line when they were giving out superhero names...

Comment: The hulk also couldn't stop the juggernaut but he could flip him up and over. Redirection.

Comment: @Daft:
He took the name entirely because he thought the whole "superhero name" thing was silly.

Comment: Was he related to Strong Bad?

Comment: The Blob isn't truly immovable, because he moves with the Earth all the time.  If he planted his feet and wound up burrowing through the Earth and shooting out the other side, then he'd be *really* immovable.  /pedant

Comment: @Liesmith, If you use the earth as your frame of reference, then he is (nigh-)immovable as specified.  ;-p

Comment: @Hellion Curse you and your legal mumbo-jumbo.